# How to click the div tag "update Patient information" after clicking the Update button in the Gridview column?

Tags: c#, html, .net, gridview

I have a update button in Gridview. When i click on Update button i need to go to div tag "Update Patient Information" to update the patient information where input text box is use to update patient information.

Comment: Need more details here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not a whole lot of information to go on here, but what you are describing sounds like you'd like to create a dynamic webpage that responds after clicking the Update button.

**jQuery** is a pretty standard solution for this. You can download it from the official jQuery site. There are multiple versions available, but almost all new web browsers support the latest version. Some developers choose older versions to support IE 8 and below. I'd download the *uncompressed developer version*; it's much easier to understand. Later on look into using a CDN to speed up load times.

The event you've described is [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/)

Here's a link to W3 Schools to get you started: [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp)